# Clean swift how to pass data back to viewController

Tags: swift, swift3

```
class ListBillPaymentFavoriteRouter: NSObject, ListBillPaymentFavoriteRoutingLogic, ListBillPaymentFavoriteDataPassing {
    weak var viewController: ListBillPaymentFavoriteViewController?
    var dataStore: ListBillPaymentFavoriteDataStore?

    // MARK: Routing

    func routeToBillPaymentInput() {
        let destinationVC = BillPaymentInputViewController.instantiate()
        var destinationDS =  destinationVC.router!.dataStore!
        passDataToBillPaymentInput(source: dataStore!, destination: &destinationDS)
        navigationToBillPaymentInput(source: viewController!, destination: destinationVC)
    }

    // MARK: Navigation

    func navigationToBillPaymentInput(source: ListBillPaymentFavoriteViewController, destination: BillPaymentInputViewController) {
        source.navigationController?.pop_FromLeftMoveToRight()
    }

    // MARK: Passing data

    func passDataToBillPaymentInput(source: ListBillPaymentFavoriteDataStore, destination: inout BillPaymentInputDataStore) {
        destination.testTest = "Yessssss"
    }


}
```

When I pop to navigationController I can't receive data

Comment: use `delegation` or `Notification`

Comment: If I don't want to use delegation Should I do?

Comment: @PuChaisirikul it's common way for iOS to use delegates. But you can use callbacks instead of them

Comment: Use swift Closure for passing data back

Comment: I think clean swift maybe have good way for pass data back to viewController

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: I knew we should could viewController, example

let index = viewController!.navigationController!.viewControllers.count - 2
        let destinationVC = viewController?.navigationController?.viewControllers[index] as! BillPaymentInputViewController

Answer (score 0):

We should could viewController, example

```
func routeToBillPaymentInput() {
    let index = viewController!.navigationController!.viewControllers.count - 2
    let destinationVC = viewController?.navigationController?.viewControllers[index] as! BillPaymentInputViewController
    var destinationDS =  destinationVC.router!.dataStore!
    passDataToBillPaymentInput(source: dataStore!, destination: &destinationDS)
    navigationToBillPaymentInput(source: viewController!, destination: destinationVC)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At all

```
class ListBillPaymentFavoriteRouter: NSObject, ListBillPaymentFavoriteRoutingLogic, ListBillPaymentFavoriteDataPassing {
weak var viewController: ListBillPaymentFavoriteViewController?
var dataStore: ListBillPaymentFavoriteDataStore?

// MARK: Routing

func routeToBillPaymentInput() {
    let index = viewController!.navigationController!.viewControllers.count - 2
    let destinationVC = viewController?.navigationController?.viewControllers[index] as! BillPaymentInputViewController
    var destinationDS =  destinationVC.router!.dataStore!
    passDataToBillPaymentInput(source: dataStore!, destination: &destinationDS)
    navigationToBillPaymentInput(source: viewController!, destination: destinationVC)
}

// MARK: Navigation

func navigationToBillPaymentInput(source: ListBillPaymentFavoriteViewController, destination: BillPaymentInputViewController) {
    source.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

// MARK: Passing data

func passDataToBillPaymentInput(source: ListBillPaymentFavoriteDataStore, destination: inout BillPaymentInputDataStore) {
    destination.testTest = "Yessssss"

}
```

}